# Why is the value of the drop-down list (button) not assigned?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have about 7 DropDownButton, so I created a class in which I just change the values. Here is my class -

```
class DropDown extends StatelessWidget {
  late List<DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>> menuItem;
  String? menuValue;
  String? hintValue;
  DropDown(this.menuItem, this.menuValue, this.hintValue);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StatefulBuilder(builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter mystate){
      return Container(
          child: DropdownButton(
            underline: Container(
              height: 0.1,
              color: Colors.transparent,
            ),
              hint: Text('$hintValue'),
              value: menuValue,
              icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
              items: menuItem,


              onChanged: (dynamic newValue) {
                mystate(() {
                  menuValue = newValue!;
              
                });
              }
          )
        )
      );
    })  ;

  }

}
```

Below is how I display these dropdowns -

```
DropDown(LoginClass.typeModemsDropDown, LoginClass.typeModemsValue, 'Выберите тип модема'),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 12,
                    ),
                    DropDown(LoginClass.vendorCountersDropDown, LoginClass.vendorCountersValue, 'text'),
```

When you try to display in the console LoginClass.vendorCountersValue - the value of null. However, if at this point, I will output print(menuValue); -

```
mystate(() {
                      menuValue = newValue!;
                  print(menuValue);
                    });
```

Then, it displays the correct values ​​in the console for me

**data** - Here is how I am getting the data -

```
LoginClass.viewModemsDropDown .add(DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>(value: resp['data'][i]['id'].toString(), child: Text(resp['data'][i]['attributes'] ['view_name']))),



 //  LoginClass.viewModemsDropDown - ["blue": 1, "red": 2] !VALUE!
```

Tell me, how can I see the values of the selected item anywhere in the code?
Can you point out my mistake and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It is working as expected on my test data, Can you include sample data with `LoginClass.typeModemsDropDown` values

Comment: `[DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>, DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>]
I/flutter ( 4822): null`

Comment: Can you provide sample data that will be present on like `["a", "b"]`

Comment: DropDownMenuItem - ["CityName","CityName"]
Value - ["1","2"]

Comment: Can you update the question including the value, I am still confused

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Please check, I have changed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a callback method on your `DropDown`. Also use named constructor cases like this.

```dart
class DropDown extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function(dynamic) callback;

  final List<DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>> menuItem;
  final String? menuValue;
  final String? hintValue;

  const DropDown({
    Key? key,
    required this.callback,
    required this.menuItem,
    required this.menuValue,
    required this.hintValue,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String? currentValue = menuValue;

    return StatefulBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter mystate) {
      return Container(
        child: DropdownButton(
          underline: Container(
            height: 0.1,
            color: Colors.transparent,
          ),
          hint: Text('$hintValue'),
          value: menuValue,
          icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
          items: menuItem,
          onChanged: (dynamic newValue) {
            mystate(() {
              currentValue = newValue!;
            });

            callback(currentValue);
          },
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

And use case

```dart
DropDown(
  menuItem: ["a", "b"]
      .map(
        (e) => DropdownMenuItem(
          child: Text(e),
          value: e,
        ),
      )
      .toList(),
  callback: (p0) {
    print(p0);
  },
  hintValue: "Set",
  menuValue: "a",
),
```

Comment: This works, but when changing the value - the hintvalue remains the same, it does not change to the actually selected element

Comment: And I'm still confused, what should I send to the server? how to send p0?

Comment: It is ok to have `hintvalue` remain the same, I am trying to have const constructor for performance cases, The actual selected item is avaialbe item from callback method with is p0

Comment: Oh, apparently this does not suit me, because the user will not be able to see what he has selected and I do not understand how to send it to the server

Comment: Actually user will be able to see, it would be easier if you run the code I posted, you can call the server inside `callback` or on `onChanged` to upload the value on server.

Comment: This is a single form, which consists of about six fields, so the user must first fill in ALL the fields, only then submit the form to the server.

Comment: I think you can create state variables on parent widget(the place you are using `DropDown`), and on submit, push those data